# Can't Insert Keyframes while in Pose mode or pullup any menu with shortcut keys in 2.92?

Tags: interface, eevee-render-engine

Like the title says I can't insert key frames or even any menu through shortcut keys while in pose mode, I don't know why, I've tried messing around but nothing. I installed a fresh copy, with a different path, and now I can but in the original I can't. So clearly it's an add-on or setting, but I don't know what could stop me from doing this cause this only happened recently. If anyone knows anything please help.

I'm in 2.92.

Edit: I looked into it and in my key binds, when I search "key" something called pose is missing in mine but not the fresh install. Does anyone know how to get them back?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found it. When you go into key binds, don't search anything, just scroll down until you see 3d view. If restore is beside it then like the arrow to drop down menu. Scroll down until you see pose, and if restore is beside it, then press it. IDK how it got removed but whatever I guess.